# query the before last object in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB and i have the following records:

```
{
    name: "a",
    status: [
        { age: 15, closed: true},
        { age: 38, closed: true},
        { age: 42, closed: false},
    ]
},
{
    name: "b",
    status: [
        { age: 29, closed: true},
        { age: 5, closed: false},
    ]
}
```

I want to check if the before last object in status has for example **age = 29**.
is there anyway to do that without using **aggregation** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) and pass `-2` as an argument to get before last element (`-1` represents last one),

> If negative, $arrayElemAt returns the element at the idx position, counting from the end of the array.

Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            beforeLast: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$status", -2 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "beforeLast.age": 29
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            beforeLast: 0
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: alternatively you can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) with [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) keyword to define a temporary variable:

```
db.col.find({
    $expr: {
        $eq: [
            29,
            {
                $let: {
                    vars: { beforeLast: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$status", -2 ] } },
                    in: "$$beforeLast.age"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: i can't use **aggregate** because m using an old version of mongo. is there anyway to use a simple query with **find**

Comment: @Ayoubk nothing comes to my mind, I believe this syntax with negative index is only available for `$arrayElemAt` operator. Any possiblites of upgrading your mongo ?

Comment: i think **$expr** allow to use aggregate operators with simple find. i wondering if it's possible ?

Comment: @Ayoubk you are right, just modified my answer, you just need `$let` with `$expr` and it works without aggregation

Comment: is there anyway to use regex instead of equal ?

Comment: @Ayoubk nothing comes to my mind at the moment, maybe you can open another question and someone might be able to help you